# Event triggered VBA Macro runs, but doesn't execute

Tags: vba, excel, execution

I have a pivot table with caculated item. Each time, when I change the parameter in the pivot main filter, text formatting goes back do default.

In order not ot format the table each time, I created a macro, that should format the pivot table whenever I put a value in cell D1. C2 is the format sample cell. It appears that macro runs, but doesn't execute.

Could You help?

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$d$1" Then

Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("C2").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ORAZ(JEŻELI($B2=" 'OFERTA/TOTAL RYNEK'";1;0);JEŻELI(C2>1;1;0))"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ORAZ(JEŻELI($B1=""OFERTA/TOTAL RYNEK"";1;0);JEŻELI(C1>1;1;0))"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("C:N").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters you need `If Target.Address = "$D$1" Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing two strings, such as `Target.Address` and `"$d$1"` using the following:

```
If Target.Address = "$d$1" Then
```

.. can never equate to `TRUE`, as if `Target.Address` did refer to column 4, row 1, it would hold the string `"$D$1"`. Using `=` to compare essentially uses *Binary Compare*.

You either need to correct it to `"$D$1"`, or use a *Text Compare* method with the `StrComp` function.

Stepping through the event, and hovering over the `Target.Address` would have highlighted this.

Comment: In fairness to OP, it took quite a while before someone pointed out to me how to step through an event procedure (which was by adding a `Stop` statement). Perhaps there are other ways.

Comment: @SJR You can set a breakpoint in the event procedure by clicking in the margin.

Comment: @VincentG - so you can, how did I never know that!

Comment: @SJR well, you can also use the F9 key, or use the toolbar button with an hand (Not sure if it shows up by default, you may have to customize the toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the other poster - the binary comparison will never evaluate you argument to `True` you could either save the address as a string and change the argument to `If Target.Address = [Assigned String Name] Then` but it's much better to just change the argument to the following:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D$1")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    'code here

End If
```

This mitigates the risk of code behaving not as you intended and also as it only passes the argument if only D1 changes and, as the comments below state, is the more appropriate code.

Comment: `If Target = Range("$D$1")` - no, that is wrong because it will compare values. Using `Address` is the way to go (or `Intersect`).

Comment: @SJR I accept you're argument and have updated my answer as a result

Comment: I wouldn't use the word *'easier'*. I'd use the word *'better'*. It's not easier (there's more to type) but is a better method. You haven't mentioned *why* though, which could help the OP. (Why - because if more than one cell is changed at once - e.g. `Target.Address = "$D$1:$D$2"`, not using `Intersect` will mean the change is ignored if looking only for a single cell address.)